# Missing Return Statement in Abstract Class and No Arguments expected

Tags: java

We were given an assignment, with 2 (complete) classes `Motorcycle` and `Car`  and where ask to create an abstract class `Vehicle`, which should also contain an abstract method (I guessed for the calculation of the vehicle tax) and an interface called `CarIF` for all public methods (I wasn't sure what that meant).

I have created the following code, and edited `Motorcycle` and `Car` so that they wouldn't contain color and `cylinderCapacity`, and created a Test file to see if it works, but when I try to compile it, I get the error of

```
missing return statement
```

in my `Vehicle` class.

Also whenever I try to add anything to `Motorcycle` in my `Test.java` I get the error that no arguments where expected. Is that because I am missing a constructor and does that mean I would need to add color and `cylinderCapacity` to the constructor in `Car` as well?

(I have them in seperate files, but I put them all together to post them here as code.)

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    private String color;
    private double cylinderCapacity;

    public double getCylinderCapacity() {
            return cylinderCapacity;
        }

    public double setCylinderCapacity(double cylinderCapacity) { //Don't change the original issue otherwise anybody looking at this question may get confused.
            this.cylinderCapacity = cylinderCapacity;
    }


    public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }

    public void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }


    public abstract double calculateMotorVehicleTax ();

    }

    public interface CarIF {

        void printInfo();

    }

    public class Motorcycle extends Vehicle implements CarIF {



    @Override
        public double calculateMotorVehicleTax() {
            return Math.ceil(cylinderCapacity / 25) * 1.84;
        }

        public void printInfo() {
            System.out.println("I'm a " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".");
        }
    }


    public class Car extends Vehicle implements CarIF {

        private int engineType;             
        private double co2Emission;         

        public Car(int engineType,  double co2Emission) {

            this.engineType = engineType;
            this.co2Emission = co2Emission;
        }

        public int getEngineType() {
            return engineType;
        }

        public double getCo2Emission() {
            return co2Emission;
        }



        @Override
        public double calculateMotorVehicleTax() {
            double tax = (engineType == 0) ? 2.0 : 9.5;
            double _co2Emission = co2Emission - 95;
            if(_co2Emission < 0) {
                _co2Emission = 0;
            }
            return Math.ceil(cylinderCapacity / 100) * tax + _co2Emission * 2.0;
        }

        public void printInfo() {
            System.out.println("I'm a " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".");
        }
    }

    public class Test {
    public static void printTax(Vehicle o) {
    System.out.print("Tax: ");
    System.out.println(o.calculateMotorVehicleTax());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car c = new Car("blue", red, 3, 5);
    Motorcycle m = new Motorcycle("red", 9,);
    printTax(c);
    printTax(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `public double setCylinderCapacity(...)` should be `public void setCylinderCapacity(...)`.

Comment: What @luk2302 says. Also, you didn't define a constructor for your Motorcycle class, so you can't pass (String, int) as parameters in your Test class.

Comment: your constructor arguments are mismatching. plz don't do this in future.

Comment: @NikRawlins. Try to refrain from changing the question after it has been answered. Otherwise anybody looking at this question in the future won't see what the problem is.

Comment: Sry didn't think about that! I have tried adding constructors to Car, Motorcycle and Vehicle, but that didn't help either. My laptop just gave up so I can't try it out, but what would happen if I just deleted all the constructors? I looked at examples we have from the teacher for similar scenarios and none of them have constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a Constructor to your Vehicle class, MotorCycle class and change the constructor in your car class. Your Vehicle constructor should look like this

```
public Vehicle(String color, Double cylinderCapacity){
this.color = color;
this.cylinderCapacity = cylinderCapacity;
}
```

Your MotorCycle constructor should look like this:

```
public MotorCycle(String color, double cyclinderCapacity){
super(color, cylinderCapacity)//this calls the vehicle constructor
}
```

Your car constructor doesn't match the arguments in the test. If you want to add color and cylindeCapacity in your car constructor just add color, and CylinderCapacity in the arguments, then in the constructor body call the super constructor like I did in the MotorCycle constructor.

Also your `double setCylinderCapacity(double cylinderCapacity)` method is missing a return type. I assume that method is only to set the value, so just change double to void eg

```
void setCylinderCapacity(double cylinderCapacity)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

If your method's return type is other then `void` then you should have `return` statement in your method that gets invoked unconditionally.

Here you have `public double setCylinderCapacity(...){}` method which has retunr type as `double` while you are not returning any `double` value. Hence `Missing return statement` occurs.

Either return `double` which is not suggested by your method name or change return type to `void`.